# d3 hover css stops working when the chart stops "ticking"

Tags: css, animation, svg, d3.js, hover

[This fiddle demonstrates the problem with hover](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/tU5zN/12/).  Basically, while the graph is animating, my hover classes work fine.  But once it settles, :hover stops working.  It's also not just pseudo CSS classes.  I also tried mouseOver/mouseOut events to add/remove a class.  This method also stops functioning.  Once you drag a node and the animation resumes, so does the hover/mouseOver.

```
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    node.attr("transform", transform);
}
//I had no idea what code to paste but it requires it with a linked fiddle.
```

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: Crap.  Chromium bug? :(

Comment: Looks like it. Also, IE11 throws a `permission denied` error when accessing `document` variable

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the bug is specific to `<foreignObject>` content: replacing with all SVG elements [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/tU5zN/15/).  I've noticed the same problem with foreignObjects not repainting properly in Chrome on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734716/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a decent workaround:

```
setInterval(function () { tick(); }, 30);
```