# Create Multiple charts on dropdown with user inputs in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to implement bar chart and pie chart similar to the example provided in d3js [http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734716/calling-alternate-chart-drawing-function-based-on-user-selection-with-d3js) with dropdown menu for user selection.

Goal is to override the existing chart with another chart with legends and labels changed. I tried the below Stack Overflow Question did not work.

[Calling alternate chart drawing function based on user selection with d3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734716/calling-alternate-chart-drawing-function-based-on-user-selection-with-d3js)

I tried making changes accordingly, but the charts are showing one after another.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body{
    width:1060px;
    margin:50px auto;
}
path {  stroke: #fff; }
path:hover {  opacity:0.9; }
rect:hover {  fill:blue; }
.axis {  font: 10px sans-serif; }
.legend tr{    border-bottom:1px solid grey; }
.legend tr:first-child{    border-top:1px solid grey; }

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {  display: none; }
.legend{
    margin-bottom:76px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.legend td{
    padding:4px 5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.legendFreq, .legendPerc{
    align:right;
    width:50px;
}

</style>
<body>

<select id="drop-down">
  <option value="line">line</option>
  <option value="line1">line1</option>
</select>

<div id='dashboard'>
</div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function dashboard(id, fData){
    var barColor = 'steelblue';
    function segColor(c){ return {low:"#807dba", Medium:"#e08214",High:"#41ab5d"}[c]; }

    // compute total for each state.
    fData.forEach(function(d){d.total=d.freq.low+d.freq.Medium+d.freq.High;});

    // function to handle histogram.
    function histoGram(fD){
        var hG={},    hGDim = {t: 60, r: 0, b: 30, l: 0};
        hGDim.w = 500 - hGDim.l - hGDim.r, 
        hGDim.h = 300 - hGDim.t - hGDim.b;

        //create svg for histogram.
        var hGsvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")

            .attr("width", hGDim.w + hGDim.l + hGDim.r)
            .attr("height", hGDim.h + hGDim.t + hGDim.b).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + hGDim.l + "," + hGDim.t + ")");

        // create function for x-axis mapping.
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, hGDim.w], 0.1)
                .domain(fD.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));

        // Add x-axis to the histogram svg.
        hGsvg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + hGDim.h + ")")
            .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

        // Create function for y-axis map.
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([hGDim.h, 0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(fD, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);

        // Create bars for histogram to contain rectangles and freq labels.
        var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(fD).enter()
    //  bars.exit().remove()
                .append("g").attr("class", "bar");
                //a

        //create the rectangles.
        bars.append("rect")

           .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return hGDim.h - y(d[1]); })
            .attr('fill',barColor)
            .on("mouseover",mouseover)// mouseover is defined below.
            .on("mouseout",mouseout);// mouseout is defined below.

        //Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
        bars.append("text").text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0])+x.rangeBand()/2; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])-5; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "Mediumdle");

        function mouseover(d){  // utility function to be called on mouseover.
            // filter for selected state.
            var st = fData.filter(function(s){ return s.State == d[0];})[0],
                nD = d3.keys(st.freq).map(function(s){ return {type:s, freq:st.freq[s]};});

            // call update functions of pie-chart and legend.    
            pC.update(nD);
            leg.update(nD);
        }

        function mouseout(d){    // utility function to be called on mouseout.
            // reset the pie-chart and legend.    
            pC.update(tF);
            leg.update(tF);
        }

        // create function to update the bars. This will be used by pie-chart.
        hG.update = function(nD, color){
            // update the domain of the y-axis map to reflect change in frequencies.
            y.domain([0, d3.max(nD, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);

            // Attach the new data to the bars.
            var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(nD);

            // transition the height and color of rectangles.
            bars.select("rect").transition().duration(500)
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1]); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return hGDim.h - y(d[1]); })
                .attr("fill", color);

            // transition the frequency labels location and change value.
            bars.select("text").transition().duration(500)
                .text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1])-5; });            
        }        
        return hG;
    }

    // function to handle pieChart.
    function pieChart(pD){
        var pC ={},    pieDim ={w:250, h: 250};
        pieDim.r = Math.min(pieDim.w, pieDim.h) / 2;

        // create svg for pie chart.
        var piesvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
            .attr("width", pieDim.w).attr("height", pieDim.h).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+pieDim.w/2+","+pieDim.h/2+")");

        // create function to draw the arcs of the pie slices.
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(pieDim.r - 10).innerRadius(0);

        // create a function to compute the pie slice angles.
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) { return d.freq; });

        // Draw the pie slices.
        piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(pD)).enter()
        //piesvg.exit().remove()
        .append("path").attr("d", arc)
            .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return segColor(d.data.type); })
            .on("mouseover",mouseover).on("mouseout",mouseout);

        // create function to update pie-chart. This will be used by histogram.
        pC.update = function(nD){
            piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(nD)).transition().duration(500)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween);
        }        
        // Utility function to be called on mouseover a pie slice.
        function mouseover(d){
            // call the update function of histogram with new data.
            hG.update(fData.map(function(v){ 
                return [v.State,v.freq[d.data.type]];}),segColor(d.data.type));
        }
        //Utility function to be called on mouseout a pie slice.
        function mouseout(d){
            // call the update function of histogram with all data.
            hG.update(fData.map(function(v){
                return [v.State,v.total];}), barColor);
        }
        // Animating the pie-slice requiring a custom function which specifies
        // how the intermediate paths should be drawn.
        function arcTween(a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) { return arc(i(t));    };
        }    
        return pC;
    }

    // function to handle legend.
    function legend(lD){
        var leg = {};

        // create table for legend.
        var legend = d3.select(id).append("table").attr('class','legend');

        // create one row per segment.
        var tr = legend.append("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(lD).enter().append("tr");
         //   tr.exit().remove()

        // create the first column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").append("svg").attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16').append("rect")
            .attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16')
            .attr("fill",function(d){ return segColor(d.type); });

        // create the second column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").text(function(d){ return d.type;});

        // create the third column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").attr("class",'legendFreq')
            .text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d.freq);});

        // create the fourth column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").attr("class",'legendPerc')
            .text(function(d){ return getLegend(d,lD);});

        // Utility function to be used to update the legend.
        leg.update = function(nD){
            // update the data attached to the row elements.
            var l = legend.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(nD);

            // update the frequencies.
            l.select(".legendFreq").text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d.freq);});

            // update the percentage column.
            l.select(".legendPerc").text(function(d){ return getLegend(d,nD);});        
        }

        function getLegend(d,aD){ // Utility function to compute percentage.
            return d3.format("%")(d.freq/d3.sum(aD.map(function(v){ return v.freq; })));
        }

        return leg;
    }

    // calculate total frequency by segment for all state.
    var tF = ['low','Medium','High'].map(function(d){ 
        return {type:d, freq: d3.sum(fData.map(function(t){ return t.freq[d];}))}; 
    });    

    // calculate total frequency by state for all segment.
    var sF = fData.map(function(d){return [d.State,d.total];});

    var hG = histoGram(sF), // create the histogram.
        pC = pieChart(tF), // create the pie-chart.
        leg= legend(tF);  // create the legend.
}
</script>

<script>
var freqData=[
{State:'WK-1',freq:{low:10, Medium:20, High:10}}
,{State:'WK-2',freq:{low:30, Medium:10, High:15}}
,{State:'WK-3',freq:{low:40, Medium:45, High:35}}
,{State:'WK-4',freq:{low:15, Medium:4, High:20}}
,{State:'WK-5',freq:{low:50, Medium:8, High:19}}

];
var freqData1=[
{State:'WK-1',freq:{low:20, Medium:20, High:10}}
,{State:'WK-2',freq:{low:10, Medium:20, High:25}}
,{State:'WK-3',freq:{low:20, Medium:25, High:35}}
,{State:'WK-4',freq:{low:65, Medium:4, High:20}}
,{State:'WK-5',freq:{low:50, Medium:8, High:19}}

];
d3.select("#drop-down").on("change", function () { 
        d3.selectAll(".alt-view").remove();
        //d3.exit().remove();
    selected = this.value;

    if(selected == "line"){dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);}
    else if(selected == "line1"){dashboard('#dashboard',freqData1);}

 });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle to demonstrate existing behavior?

Comment: Ashutosh Upadhyay plz find link from plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/bTlRSNIZPbmenALcJsK0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed your plunker. The issue is that you are trying to remove the previous charts using below call.

```
d3.selectAll(".alt-view").remove();
```

However, while building chart elements, you have not assigned `alt-view` class to any of the elements. All the elements you want to remove, make sure they are contained in a parent element that has `alt-view` class and you should be good to go.

Alternatively, you can do following to quickly test this.
Replace

```
d3.selectAll(".alt-view").remove();
```

with

```
d3.selectAll("#dashboard").remove();
d3.select('body').append('div').attr('id', 'dashboard');
```

Comment: Done:-) Can you please also tell me how to change the names of legend for pie chart. say from low to low1 , medium to medium1 , high to high1 when user changed the dropdown item from line to line1

Comment: Unable to save changes to your plunker. Let me create a new one and share

Comment: This Worked Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you plz help me with this problem as well? tnx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705995/d3js-load-chart-data-from-external-csv-file